# Finish an activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

In my application I have 2 fragment, Fragment A and Fragment B.On both these fragments Iam doing some XML parsing and populating listviews.I want to implement a splash screen for my app.So that it display during parsing and population of listviews and finishes when its done. For this, I have created an activity SplashActivity.I have Implemented asyntask on FragmentA and  called the SplashActivity on preexecute section.Now, when the app launches SplashActivity get started.But I cant finish this acitivity on postexecute of FragmentA. getActivity().finishActivity() is not working.Please some one help me to solve this issue or suggest me another method to implement Splash screen on Fragment Activity.  Thanks in advance....

here is my FragmentA=>

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating layout
        View v = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.headlines_fragment, container, false);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Tag", "onCreateView");

        // We set clear listener
        loading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        if (Headlines.headflag == "malayalam") {
            urls = "http://www.abc.com/rssfeeds/19_18_17_25/1/rss.xml";

        }

        if (Headlines.headflag == "english") {
            urls = "http://www.abc.com/en/rssfeeds/1_2_3_5/latest/rss.xml";

        }

        new ProgressAsyncTask().execute();

        MainActivity.refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new ProgressAsyncTask().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    public void populate_listview() {

        newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // looping through all song nodes <song>

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            newsList.add(map);
            MarqueeStr = MarqueeStr + " *** " + Title[i];

        }

    }

    public void StartProgress() {
        new ProgressAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    public class ProgressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            myProgress = 0;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Splash.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 5); //Here I called Splash Activity

            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            getActivity().finishActivity(5);// Here I tried to finish flash activity

            if (Title == null) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());

                alertbox.setMessage("Error in connection.Do you want to retry");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("retry",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                // getActivity().finish();
                                // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                // MainActivity.class);
                                // startActivityForResult(intent,1);

                            }

                        });

                alertbox.setNegativeButton("exit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                // getActivity().finish();

                            }

                        });

                alertbox.show();

            }

            list = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter = new HeadlinesAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/karthika.TTF");
            MainActivity.flashnews.setText(MarqueeStr);
            if (Headlines.headflag == "malayalam") {
                MainActivity.flashnews.setTypeface(tf);

            }
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent myintent = new Intent(
                            "com.abc.malayalam2headlinespodcast.PODCAST");
                    Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
                    mybundle.putInt("number", position);
                    myintent.putExtras(mybundle);

                    startActivity(myintent);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parse();

            if (Title != null) {
                populate_listview();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public static void parse() {

           //parsing done here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to answer the question which is your title actually "To finish an activity from Fragment", it's always a good way to use interface to interact from Fragment to Activity as per the docs: [Communicating with Activity from Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). So one must always declare an interface in Fragment which is to be implemented in your activity something like below:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements FragmentA.FragmentListenerCallback {

   public void onFragmentInteraction() {
       //finish your activity or do whatever you like
       finish();
   }       
}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
   private FragmentListenerCallback fragmentListenerCallback;

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
     fragmentListenerCallback = (FragmentListenerCallback) activity;
   }

   public interface FragmentListenerCallback {
       void onFragmentInteraction();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       if(fragmentListenerCallback != null){
            fragmentListenerCallback.onFragmentInteraction();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not implement your Splash as an `Activity` but rather as a `DialogFragment`. Simply style that dialog fragment so that it appears fullscreen.

Concerning showing:

```
SplashDialogFragment splashDlg = new SplashDialogFragment();
splashDlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SplashScreen");
```

Then closing:

```
SplashDialogFragment splashDlg = (SplashDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findByTag("SplashScreen");
splashDlg.dismiss();
```